# adding user role on my page that redirect to user or admin page

Tags: roles, restrict

how can I add user role on my codes redirecting to admin or user page, btw here's my code.

i tried other button but it doesnt work

```
<?php

session_start();

require 'lib/password.php';

require 'connect.php';


if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $username = !empty($_POST['username']) ? trim($_POST['username']) : null;
    $passwordAttempt = !empty($_POST['password']) ? trim($_POST['password']) : null;

    $sql = "SELECT id, username, password FROM users WHERE username = :username";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->bindValue(':username', $username);

    $stmt->execute();

    $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if($user === false){
        die('Incorrect username / password combination!');
    } else{
        $validPassword = password_verify($passwordAttempt, $user['password']);

        if($validPassword){

            $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
            $_SESSION['logged_in'] = time();

            header('Location: pages/manageinformation.php');
            exit;

        } else{
            die('Incorrect username / password combination!');
        }
    }

}

?>
```

I expect output on adding user role on redirect to other page like on admin or user page